# Laravel I can't capture data as I want

Tags: database, laravel

I want to pull the data from the database like this

```
[0] => stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 6
    [parts_brand] => 1
    [car_make] => 19
    [year_range] => 2000-2002
    [category] => 1
    [sale_price] => 234
    [statement] => <p>deneme</p>
    [piece] => 12
    images => array(
           [0] => frontend/assets/img/parts/2019-11-11-13-26-45-4.jpeg
           [1] => frontend/assets/img/parts/thumb/2019-11-11-13-26-45-4_thumb.jpeg
           [2] => frontend/assets/img/parts/2019-11-11-13-26-45-3.jpeg
           [3] => frontend/assets/img/parts/thumb/2019-11-11-13-26-45-3_thumb.jpeg
       )
)
```

but it attracts it this way:

```
[0] => stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 6
    [serial_number] => deneme
    [part_name] => Fren Diski
    [parts_brand] => 1
    [car_make] => 19
    [year_range] => 2000-2002
    [category] => 1
    [sale_price] => 234
    [statement] => <p>deneme</p>
    [piece] => 12
    [image] => frontend/assets/img/parts/2019-11-11-13-26-45-4.jpeg
    [thumb] => frontend/assets/img/parts/thumb/2019-11-11-13-26-45-4_thumb.jpeg
)

[1] => stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 6
    [serial_number] => deneme
    [part_name] => Fren Diski
    [parts_brand] => 1
    [car_make] => 19
    [year_range] => 2000-2002
    [category] => 1
    [sale_price] => 234
    [statement] => <p>deneme</p>
    [piece] => 12
    [image] => frontend/assets/img/parts/2019-11-11-13-26-45-3.jpeg
    [thumb] => frontend/assets/img/parts/thumb/2019-11-11-13-26-45-3_thumb.jpeg
)
```

I'm new to laravel. Trying to learn. Thank you to everyone in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please post your code which you already tried?

Comment: Do you want to merge result from index 1 in index 0?

Comment: Please show code where you get this result

Comment: yes I want to show the image and thumb in a single array by combining the return of join in the above code